# How can I use this api to pull video streams instead of pictures?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm pretty new at this and would really appreciate the help, Thank you!

The link to jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/82wNq/38/
link to the api https://github.com/justintv/Twitch-API/blob/master/v2_resources/streams.md#get-streamsfeatured

Here is the javascript:

```
$.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/search/streams?q=all&limit=3&type=suggest&callback=?", function (data) {
    var temp = "";

    $.each(data.streams, function (index, item) {
        temp = temp + "<div class='panel-heading'><h3 class='panel-title'></h3><div id='content1'>" + item.channel.display_name + "</div><div id='content2'>" + item.viewers + "</div></div><div class='panel-body'><div id='content3'><img src='" + item.preview.medium + "'/></div></div>";
    });
    $("#content").html(temp);
});
```

and here is the html that I have so far:

```
<div id="content" class="panel panel-default"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just feed the streams into an embedded object, per their documentation.

Read up:  https://github.com/justintv/Twitch-API/blob/master/embedding.md

Comment: I can do that with a static link, I'm trying to make it where the api populates a list with streams and then feed them into the embedded player upon clicking it. any idea? Here is what I currently have, how do I modify it in order to make it work with the embedded player? http://jsfiddle.net/82wNq/59/

Comment: StackOverflow exists to help people with programming problems, not to teach them how to program.  There are plenty of resources for that already.  [Read this book.](http://www.amazon.com/JavaScript-Definitive-Guide-Activate-Guides/dp/0596805527/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1389329876&sr=8-2&keywords=javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Heres an example of what you want I have added a search function to the site aswell

jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/F4tsM/10/

Hope this helps

here is the object you need aswell

```
var obj = "<object style=opacity:1; type=application/x-shockwave-flash" + " height=378 width=620 id=live_embed_player_flash bgcolor=#000000" + " data=http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel=" + item.channel.name + ">" + "<param name=allowFullScreen value=true /><param name=allowScriptAccess value=always />" + "<param name=allowNetworking value=all />" + "<param name=movie value=http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf />" + "<param name=flashvars value=hostname=www.twitch.tv&channel=" + item.channel.name + "&auto_play=true&start_volume=25 />" + "</object>";
```

all of this is in the fiddle example awell